# Counting the number of Colourfilled cells

Tags: vba, excel, macros

[image]I am trying to find the number of colourfilled cells in B coloumn. I want to count and display the number of cour filled coloumns

But I am getting error :

```
Dim sum As Long
Dim count As Long
     sum = 0
count = 0
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*),*.xl*", Title:="Open data")
    Set Target = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set tabWS = Target.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    ' lastrow = tabWS.Range("D" & tabWS.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row  'Trigger Description starts from 2 row A coloumn
        lastrow = tabWS.Range("B" & tabWS.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row  'Trigger Description starts from 2 row A coloumn
        For j = 2 To lastrow
        If tabWS.Cells(j, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
        sum = sum + tabWS.Cells(j, 8).value
        count = count + 1
        End If
        Next j

        MsgBox ("the value is" & sum)
        End sub
```

I am getting error for sum = sum +tabs.cell(j,8).value

I can't figure it out whyI am getting this error. Can any one give me a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're opening the Workbook each time you use a method on tabWS. Try setting tabWS equal to the following instead:

```
tabWS = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
```

Now when you're setting your lastrow and sum variables in the latter part of your code you won't be trying to open the workbook over and over again.

Edit (continued from comment below)*:

```
    lastrow = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & Worksheets("Tabelle1").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row  
    For j = 2 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(j, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
    sum = sum + Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(j, 8).value
    count = count + 1
    End If
    Next j

    MsgBox ("the value is" & sum)
    End sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that you need to change the type of variable that tabWS is. Could you try removing tabWS completely? Your code would look like the following: * (code posted above in edited answer)

Comment: Oh okay, sorry for the confusion. Are you sure that all of the values in Cells(j, 8) are of type long? You might want to try using: sum = sum + CLng(tabWS.Cells(j, 8).value)

Comment: I have upated the image . Only I need to count green coloured cells

Comment: Okay, are you still getting the error message on the sum?

Comment: Did you try sum = sum + CLng(tabWS.Cells(j, 8).value)?

Comment: Can't you just increment sum by 1 (sum = sum + 1) instead of adding the value of whatever is in Cells(j,8)?